# Convert Keras (TensorFlow) MaxPooling3d to PyTorch MaxPool3d

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, max-pooling

I'm Trying to convert some Keras (TensorFlow) code to Pytorch, and I'm unable to reproduce the MaxPooling3d in Keras (TensorFlow) as MaxPool3d in PyTorch.

The following code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kernel_size = (10, 10, 2)
strides = (32, 32, 2)
in_tensor = torch.randn(1, 1, 256, 256, 64)

tf_out = layers.MaxPooling3D(data_format='channels_first', pool_size=kernel_size,
                                                    strides=strides, padding='same')(in_tensor.detach().numpy())
pt_out = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=strides)(in_tensor)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
axs = fig.subplots(1,2)
axs[0].matshow(pt_out[0,0,:,:,0].detach().numpy())
axs[0].set_title('PyTorch')
axs[1].matshow(tf_out.numpy()[0,0,:,:,0])
axs[1].set_title('TensorFlow')
```

Gives very different results:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Is the padding in the PyTorch version inorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The padding is not the same in both layers, that's why you're not getting the same results.

You set `padding='same'` in  tensorflow `MaxPooling3D` layer, but there is no padding set in pytorch `MaxPool3d` layer.

Unfortunately, in Pytorch, there is no option for 'same' padding for `MaxPool3d` as in tensorflow. So, you will need to manually pad the tensor before passing it to the pytorch `MaxPool3d` layer.

Try this code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kernel_size = (10, 10, 2)
strides = (32, 32, 2)
in_tensor = torch.randn(1, 1, 256, 256, 64)

tf_out = layers.MaxPooling3D(data_format='channels_first', pool_size=kernel_size,
                                                    strides=strides)(in_tensor.detach().numpy())
in_tensor = F.pad(in_tensor, (0, 0, 0, 0))
pt_out = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=strides)(in_tensor)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
axs = fig.subplots(1,2)
axs[0].matshow(pt_out[0,0,:,:,0].detach().numpy())
axs[0].set_title('PyTorch')
axs[1].matshow(tf_out.numpy()[0,0,:,:,0])
axs[1].set_title('TensorFlow')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
I need to use the 'same' padding, how can I achieve similar effect in PyTorch?

Comment: @ido4848 I have updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: It does not give the same result as in 'same' padding in Keras.